# How to use colors in complete outputs in bash?

Tags: bash, colors, autocomplete

I am using bash 4.4. I have colors enabled, and I see colors when hitting for example double tab after a `ls` command (files and folders in different colors). I have inside my ~/.inputrc the `set colored-stats on` setup.

However I am still not able to use colors with the `complete` command. For example, I have the following test file:

```
colored_output="\033[0;31mPaul\033[0m"
echo -e $colored_output  # this prints 'Paul' in red

_hello () {
    COMPREPLY=()
    COMPREPLY+=("Bob")
    COMPREPLY+=("Alice")
    COMPREPLY+=("${colored_output}")
}

complete -o nosort -o filenames -F _hello hello
```

when sourcing it, `Paul` is printed in red as it should. But things do not work when hitting double tab on hello (all of this displays in the default terminal color):

```
$ hello [hitting TAB TAB now]
Bob                    Alice                  \033[0;31mPaul\033[0m
```

Any idea how to get color after the TAB autocompletion too? I think I somehow need to say to `complete` that `\` should be used as an escape char?

Comment: FYI, I'm trying the same ~/.inputrc commands with Bash 4.3.48 under Ubuntu 16.04 and Bash 5.0.17 under Mint 20: 'set keyseq-timeout 1200' and 'set colored-completion-prefix on'.  It works under Mint/Bash 5.0.17 but it does not work under Bash 4.3.48 on Ubuntu 16.04. It might be related to the version of readline though (but have not yet found how to check that).

Comment: Try different combinations of putting your `echo -e $colored_output` in different quotes.  For example `echo -e "${colored_output}"` or `echo -e '${colored_output}'`.

Comment: BTW, I would expect the single-quote one to do the complete wrong thing, but it's worth a try.